# Page reloads after getting a Firebase storage link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I work on page form, where I try to edit some data and then push them back to Firebase. Edited data from text fields are working fine when saved.

On this page form  are also images, based on links retrieved from firebase storage and buttons to delete those pics, when needed. Pics are showing fine.

```
{links.length && links.map((link, i) => (
  <div>
   <img key={i} src={link} alt="loaded" height="100" width="100"/>
   <button
     className="btn btn-danger"
     onClick={this.onDeletePic.bind(this, link)}
     ><i className="fas fa-times"></i>
   </button>
  </div>
))}
```

delete button click is handled by function (for testing, just for now )

```
onDeletePic = (link) => {
  console.log('link to delete', link)
}
```

when button is clicked, I see `link to delete` in console

```
link to delete https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/site.appspot.com/o/img%2F-LIwD570ojGyu8fbNqXA%2Fimages.jpeg?alt=media&token=3457eb05-deac-4d03-91ee-10d8afc3e93d
```

and page immediately reloads just like after POST request (I checked "preserve log" in console) **Navigated** is written in blue

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/item/edit/-LIwD570ojGyu8fbNqXA?title=HP245&details= ... ightadj=on&portrait=on&gaming=on
```

Why this may happen? There is no event, so nothing to prevent. I only got a link, nothing more.

Comment: Is your button inside a `form` element? If that's the case, you must send the `event` to `onDeletePic` as well and run `event.preventDefault()` so that the default browser behavior of reloading the browser is prevented.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, all that code is inside a big parent form.  Thanks, I' try that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your buttons are inside a form you must prevent the default behavior of a submitted form which is to reload the browser.

You could pass in the event as well as the `link` to your `onDeletePic` function and use `event.preventDefault` to prevent the reload.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  onDeletePic = (event, link) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("link to delete", link);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* ... */}
        {links.length &&
          links.map((link, i) => (
            <div>
              <img key={i} src={link} alt="loaded" height="100" width="100" />
              <button
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={event => this.onDeletePic(event, link)}
              >
                <i className="fas fa-times" />
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank U very much, just did that